# Drawing graphs on circles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, algorithms

Please consider the following problem:

Given: a simple graph (without self-loops and without multiple edges) $G$ on $n$ vertices.

Task: place equidistantly the vertices of $G$ on a circle of unit radius and draw the edges of $G$ in such a way that their total length is minimized.

What is the complexity of this problem?

What is the relevant literature?

Comment: I have heard that this problem is NP-hard, because it has a fairly quick reduction to the max-cut problem.  Lovasz had some result with a name like "rubber bands and springs", which approximated solutions using a sphere in $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: you probably mean "from" MAX CUT ? 

Comment: @Suresh: Yes.$ $

Comment: Rubber bands, convex embeddings and graph connectivity by N. Linial, L. Lovász and A. Wigderson may be the Lovasz paper mentioned above.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

As S. Carnahan and Kristal Cantwell mentions it in the comments, this problem is NP-hard. See:

Rubber bands, convex embeddings and graph connectivity by N. Linial, L. Lovász and A. Wigderson